# plutil equivalent in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, server

I've been using `plutil` (built-in in OSX) to read plists. However, I'm unable to find that on Linux's `apt-get`. Does anyone have an idea which package `plutil` is in? I'm currently using Ubuntu Server 14.04.3.

Comment: Why do you need to read plists? It's Ubuntu.

Comment: Here: http://scw.us/iPhone/plutil/

Answer (score 6):

`plistutil` is the command you need to be using in Linux.

Install the package using

```
sudo apt-get install libplist-utils
```

Then either replace all `plutil` to `plistutil` in your script, or create a symlink (assuming your `plistutil` was installed at `/usr/bin/plistutil`) like so:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/plistutil /usr/bin/plutil
```

To determine where your `plistutil` was installed, run `which plistutil`.

Answer (score 2):

In case it's still relevant, [Screenplay](https://screenplay.dev/) currently maintains an open-source, cross-platform, drop-in replacement for `plutil`:

https://github.com/screenplaydev/plutil

It's based on Facebook's xcbuild (a tool developed by them to build xcode projects on Linux), but stripped down to just provide plist-editting functionality.